# Starting another Ph.D. position in another country in Europe

Tags: visa

I am Iranian and studying for a Ph.D. in Poland. I started this position with a scholarship around 2 weeks ago. I have a D type Schengen visa. Now, I have been offered a position in the Netherlands. I just want to know whether I can apply for a visa from inside Poland or I should do anything else? Anybody have experience with this?

Comment: Since you are presently a **resident** of Poland, you should be able to make an application in Poland.

Comment: Hello. You should not use an answer as a way to call attention to your question. You can edit your question if you want to add information. The answer you published is probably going to be discarded as _not an answer_.

Comment: I am not a resident of Poland. I just reside in Poland

Comment: You are resident of Poland if you reside in Poland with a valid residence permit or national long-stay visa and registered your address with Polish authorities.

Comment: A quick email to the Dutch consulate will answer your question definitively.